# Formulario de contacto y archivo adjunto php

Tags: php, html, formularios, email

Tengo un formulario de contacto que debe enviar un archivo adjunto, el problema es que no envía el correo ni el archivo, ya he mirado en spam y demás y no tengo ni idea porqué no lo envía, ya lo intente con correos de Gmail y Hotmail y simplemente no los envía.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Para y asunto del mensaje a enviar
        $email_to = "correo@gmail.com"; 
        $email_subject = "Cotización de pagina Web";    
        //variables para los campos
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo']; // required
        $Colores = $_POST['Colores']; // required
        $Medida = $_POST['Medida']; // required
        $nombre = $_POST['Nombre']; // required
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

        //variables para los datos del archivo 
        $nombrearchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        // Leemos el archivo a adjuntar
        $archivo = file_get_contents($archivo);
        $archivo = chunk_split(base64_encode($archivo));

        // Cuerpo del Email
        $message =  "Nombre: ".$nombre ."\n\n".
                "telefono: ". $telefono."\n\n" . 
                "Correo: " . $email_from. "\n\n" .
                "Medida: " . $Medida. "\n\n" . 
                "Colores: " . $Colores. "\n\n" . 
                "Durabilidad: " .  $tipo . "\n\n" . 
                $_POST['message'];

        //cabecera del email (forma correcta de codificarla)
        $headers = "From:" . $email_from ."\r\n";
                    'Reply-To:'.$email_from ."\r\n";
                    'X-Mailer:PHP/'.phpversion();

        //armando mensaje del email
        $message = "--=A=G=R=O=\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= $CuerpoMensaje . "\r\n\r\n";

        //archivo adjunto  para email    
        $email_message .= "--=A=G=R=O=\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $nombrearchivo . "\"\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $nombrearchivo . "\"\r\n\r\n";
        $email_message .= $archivo . "\r\n\r\n";
        $email_message .= "--=A=G=R=O=--";


    mail($email_to,$message,$headers) ;
    }       
?>
```

**HTML:**

```html
<form action="email-form.php" method="post">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label>
    Seleccione el tipo de tapete
    </label>
    <select name="tipo[]">
    <option value="premier">
    Premier
    </option>
    <option value="comercial">
    Comercial
    </option>
    <option value="promocional">
    Promocional
    </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="Colores" class="form-control" placeholder="Medida Base por Altura">
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="Medida" class="form-control" placeholder="Color Fondo/Logotipo">
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Archivo NO mayor a 2 MB</label>
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="exampleInputFile">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect">Enviar</button>
  <p class="aviso">Al dar click en el botón de Enviar, usted acepta nuestras <a href="aviso-de-privacidad.html">politicas de privacidad</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Proporciona un fragmento de tu implementan, cuando accionas el envio del correo y  menciona versión de PHP y que librerías utilizas. --> [ask]

Comment: Cuando le doy enviar formulario solo me pone la pagina en blanco y cabe mencionar que estoy aprendiendo PHP

Comment: @NoemiCeron cheando la documentación de [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) te hace falta `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en el formulario para el envio de archivos y podrias realizar un `echo` al final del archivo PHP para ver si todo se realizo de manera correcta.

Comment: @NoemiCeron , da una vuelta a esta respuesta en SO ingles, cuando envias archivos, tu formulario debe contener enctype="multipart/form-data necesariamente.--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail